# Model transparent in material preview

Tags: modeling

Ok so, whenever I go in material preview the model is transparent. This happens with every model that I've been doing. If anybody could explain it would be great.
[image: The model is transparent, making it harder to do stuff with.]

Comment: Consider uploading your blend file on https://blend-exchange.com to receive a faster solution

Comment: Hello :). Eevee does this with alpha blend materials. Check your material settings.

Comment: Ok, woops. I'm blind, I found it in Material Settings. Sorry bout' that.